# pods error while pull the code

Tags: ios, cocoapods, bitbucket, podspec

I have installed the pods in my project.Every time I pull the code from bitbucket getting pods error.Because of this error every time I'm reinstalling the pods when I pull the code.Is there any other solution to resolve this issue.Can anyone please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.gitignore` to your project and add following into that file:

```
**/**.DS_Store
**/**.orig
**/xcuserdata
(YourProjectName)/Pods
.DS_Store
```

It won't add some of the files that you don't want in your version control.

You can find more about this [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

Git stores your changes, it is not designed to store things that can be derived (compiler intermediates, downloadable dependencies, user data, etc...). So the solution is to put them under a `.gitignore` file, which instructs git to ignore those files when adding all files to commit.

If you want a .gitignore file for any environment, use [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/).  For iOS, request a gitignore for `macOS`, `CocoaPods`

So, your pods will not be affected on anyone who clone the project. He must use `pod install` on his own copy.  This gitignore will not affect the `Podfile` itself